# Why did Hibernate put out a new release of the JPA2 API?

Tags: java, hibernate, api, jpa, jpa-2.0

Running the versions plugin for Maven, I found the following:

```
[INFO]   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api ...
[INFO]                                               1.0.0.Final -> 1.0.1.Final
```

Anyone have any idea why this artifact was upgraded from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1?  Where one can go to learn more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell why it was updated, but what was updated: Eclipse Public License v1.0 and Eclipse Distribution License v. 1.0 was added. This produced licence.txt and readme.txt and new header section in every file.

I made diff to sources. So sources are same (except comments), but result of compilation can of course be different. Just checked javax/persistence.LockModeType.class, only difference is in LineNumberTable (which is expected, because of comments added to source)

Comment: Did you do a diff on the JARs to figure this out?  Meaning...are the classes identical?

Comment: I will update it to answer to answer, originally I made diff to sources.